# Add variables (that are not the attributes of table given in setTableName() )in storage of zend_auth in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have the code as:

```
            $authAdapter = $this->getAuthAdapter();
            $authAdapter->setIdentity($username)
                        ->setCredential($password);
            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
```

where getAuthAdapter() is as follows:

```
    protected function getAuthAdapter() {
    $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);

    $authAdapter->setTableName('credentials')
            ->setIdentityColumn('employee_id')
            ->setCredentialColumn('password');


    return $authAdapter;
}

             $userInfo = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null, 'password');
             # the default storage is a session with namespace Zend_Auth
             $authStorage = $auth->getStorage();
             $authStorage->write($userInfo);
```

Here I have used table named credentials.But I want to store a variable in auth_storage which is not the attribute of table credentials.So that I can use that variable later from that storage as given below.So how this should be done??

```
             $userInfo = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read();
```

I can do by the following code:
If I want to add a variable named $var then

```
                $var = new stdClass; 
                $userInfo->var = 'Variable';
```

But I dont think its good idea.Any other solution ??Please reply fast as its urgently required.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store some data from other table from database you can get an instance of authentication select and join with that table(s):

```
$authSelect = $authAdapter->getDbSelect();
$authSelect->join(TABLE, CONDITION, COLUMNS);

$result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
```